# Fancybox image click works isolated but not with my other code

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

So my problem is that when clicking an image to enable fancybox *embedded with all my other code*, the function is no longer working. Can anyone find why?
I tried to put the image before the container and thumbnail class but no luck..
First, I give you all my code (which makes fancybox not work), and below is the isolated code that makes the image pop up just fine as I want it to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
    <header>
     <a href="#">TITLE</a>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CCC</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
           </ul></li>
           <li><a href="#">DDD</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
              </ul></li>
           <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <div class='container'>
     <div class="thumbnail">
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a class="fancybox" href="images/image1.jpg"><img src="images/image1.jpg"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a class="fancybox" href="image2.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">      
              <a class="fancybox" href="image3.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a class="fancybox" href="image4.jpg"><img src="image4.jpg"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a class="fancybox" href="image5.jpg"><img src="image5.jpg"></a>
           </div>
        </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script scr='bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src="http://goo.gl/1yIJUX"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that is working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/image1.JPG"><img src="images/image1.JPG" alt="" /></a>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A better description of what it does (not) do, other than "it does not work", may be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't activate the fancybox function when I click the image link. I get linked to the image on a new page, as if there were no fancybox enabled.

Comment: @Jongware - I edited my question. Would u look at it again? Thank you

Comment: You are loading jQuery twice. Normally you only need a single version of jQuery and loaded before any other plugin

Comment: What should I do not to load jQuery twice? Tried removing different links, but nothing works.. @JFK

Comment: One reason for not loading jQuery twice is that it does not make sense, and makes your web page slower. A second reason is that yes, loading  jQuery twice can cause problems. A third reason is that you should always present the simplest code that reproduces your problem. If someone sees an obvious problem in your code, why should he bother looking for other problems? Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Probably it cannot find the fancybox css and js files. It is suspicious that the URLs start with a slash: if you have a "fancybox " subdirectory, you should have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

Comment: U were right about not being able to find the css or js files. Some tutorial told me to link to jquery.pack.js, but I changed it to jquery.js only, and now it works in my cleaned out example. BUT it still doesn't work in my other files where I linked to bootstrap and such other. Does the hierarchy of linking here matter? the .fancybox class is within other classes, does that matter as well?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If somebody answers your question, you should accept it, and if you have further questions you should ask them in new questions instead of completely rewriting the old one. Think about how confusing this will be for future readers.

Comment: `If somebody answers your question, you should accept it` **if** you think is the correct answer ;)

Comment: @JFK well, in this case the OP commented that "U were right", and then rewrote the question completely because he had new unrelated problems... (and included my answer in the "This is the code that is working fine" part)

Comment: Hi there, sorry for being confusing. My problem of Fancybox not working still remained after I fixed the slash issue (but thanks for that, @lbalazscs ). Also, I was banned to make a new question and stackoverflow told me to rewrite the existing one, that's why I did it.